# Is there a method to represent arbitrary length tuple in Clingo?

Tags: answer-set-programming, clingo

If I wanna get the head of an arbitrary length tuple,
I have to code like:
head(A) :- tuple(A,B).
head(A) :- tuple(A,B,C).
head(A) :- tuple(A,B,C,D).
.......

Is there a method could represent 
head(A) :- tuple(A...).

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to represent tuples with different arity? If not, then you could represent tuples as lists, i.e. the `tuple(d,e,f)` could be represented as `tuple(d, tuple(e, tuple(f, nil))).`. Then, the head predicate could be defined as `head(X) :- tuple(X, _).`

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible solutions:

**Avoid terms with different arity**

This can be done by changing the representation of tuples:

```
tuple(a, nil).
tuple(b, tuple(c, nil)).
tuple(d, tuple(e, tuple(f, nil))).

head(X) :- tuple(X, _).
```

**Use External Functions in Clingo**

Clingo supports the definition of external functions see [Python API](https://potassco.org/clingo/python-api/5.4) and the [guide](https://github.com/potassco/guide/releases/download/v2.2.0/guide.pdf). For instance, we can write functions in Python that can manipulate terms. As a workaround, I suggest using a further constructor for terms, here `c`.

```
#script (python)
import clingo
def head(x):
      return x.arguments[0]
#end.

tuple(c(1)).
tuple(c(2,3)).
head(@head(X)) :- tuple(X).
```